# How can i add the same value in to the different tables that are in different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am having 2 databases namely ach and cart and i am having tables namelt Register and Invoice i would like to add a field in to those 2 tables . Like if i enter a value like some ccyyxxyxyxa this should be saved in the 2 tables...

Comment: Could you explain a bit further, please - it's not clear when you want this operation to be performed.

Comment: While editing i would like to perform this operation.. I would like to replace the existing with the current one in both tables

Comment: But do you mean using an SQL statement, or in some other language (i.e. in PHP through a webpage)?

Comment: I am doing in asp.net with c# coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options , you can either insert/update same value from your code(c#) or write a trigger on one database that will insert/update the field on other database.

Answer (score 0):

If there form one transaction then you can either use MSDTC or another option can be of Linked Servers in SQL

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have a lot of solutions.

Things I would try are:

1. Using local transaction MSDTC if you want your modify for the database inside transaction.
   At this case, first you need to set up MSDTC service for your computer which have database.
   Then, using .NET transaction to add data to different database.
2. using local transaction, like 3td party tool, for example seasar.net has transaction for this case.
3. using Link at Database which to add data to different server.